# How to find Python module from both within and above working directory

Tags: python

I have a Python project with file structure similar to this

```
├── project-folder
├── main_script.py
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helpers.py
│   ├── mod1.py
│   ├── mod2.py
```

Within `main_script.py` I use functions from `mod1.py` and `mod2.py`. Both `mod1.py` and `mod2.py` `import helpers`. If I directly run `mod1.py` it is able to correctly find `helpers`, but when I run `main_script.py`, it's throwing a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'`.

I can get around this issue by adding either of the below to `mod1.py` and `mod2.py`, but I'm wondering if there's a better method that doesn't require me adding this code to every module within `modules`.

**Method 1:**

```
import sys
import os
file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(file_dir)
```

**Method 2:**

```
try:
    import helpers 
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from . import helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `__init__.py` to the same directory as `main_script.py` and then call the import statement like so:

```py
import modules.helpers
```